# Clearcase remote client 7.0.1 file "download" problem on Windows 7

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I want to create a view of a folder  server using the remote client 7.0.1.
When the view is created I can see all the folders, but not a single file.
We tried to update the view several times and it didn’t help.
We can see the files in the left pane (’`Clearcase Navigator`’) of the remote client but not locally on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you did add the right loading rules?

Views on a CCRC are 'web' (*snapshot*) views, meaning they need to be loaded on the disk through load rules.

---

As the [OP reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946183/clearcase-remote-client-7-0-1-file-download-problem-on-windows-7/4955904#4955904), you need to be registered in the right group to access files: i.e in one of the groups of the Vob you want to explore.

And I wouldn't recommend selected the 'by default' group in the CCRC preferences:

[image: ccrc preferences for group]

I prefer setting explicitly the name of the group.

Comment: The load rules are set and the folders are created, but all the files are missing.

Comment: @Lorant: note, on the `ClearCase Navigator` left panel, I only see directories, no files. Only in the ClearCase Details right view do I see directories and files.

Comment: @Lorant: after that, you need to check the rights for the user to access files: what is the main group set in the CCRC preferences? What is the element protection rights for any of the directory?

Comment: The main group is set to the default. The protection rights for the directory is set to rwx for Owner, Group and other, I check one of the file too, it is set to read for Owner, Group and other. And you are right, the files are not visible, only in the Clearcase Details window.

Comment: @Lorant: Err... the "default"? It needs to be one of the groups (primary or secondary) of the Vob you want to access through your view.

Comment: Yeah, there is a radio button, the first option say "Default". I found out in the meantime that in another directory there are files which can be downloaded to my computer, but the files I want cant be downloaded.

Comment: @Lorant: I don't think this is enough. You need to explicitly set the right group, meaning select the radio button "Use defined groups", and enter one of the groups of the Vob you want to access (provided you are registered in that group as well): then create a *new* view and try again. The files should then be loaded.

Comment: @VonC thx for the help, it turned out, that it is a permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that it was permission/group membership problem. I was not registered in the group which has access to the files I want.

Comment: I have completed my answer with your conclusion as well as an illustration on CCRC group preferences.